# How to show your app on spotlight search

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8

how should I make my app appear on spotlight search result while searching on iPhone iOS8 ?
Is it connected to the app store rating or something to do with meta data
Sample attached [image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about App Store search results, not programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on many variables. In short, the more popular the app is, the higher the odd it gets on spotlight search. Number of downloads, rate, etc… Even the user's geographical location ( popular apps around me) are all important. Also if your app is  unique , it's easy to get on the search results.

I think apple told about this in WWDC, but I don't really remember which session is that.